# Javascript variable scope outside functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the scope of an array in javascript?

How can I resolve this situation?

```
var parseXlsx = require('excel');
var arrayURLToSearch = [];
parseXlsx('foo.xlsx', function(err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;
    for(var i=1; i<2; i++){
        arrayURLToSearch[i] = data[i][0];
    }
});
console.log(arrayURLToSearch[0]); -> undefined
```

How can I print the `arrayURLToSearch` outside the function?

Comment: What do you mean outside the function? what is your exact scenario that you want to acheive? If you have no specific scenario, just put console.log(arrayURLToSearch[0]); after the "for" loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The callback happens at some point in the future that you cannot predict.  Try this instead:

```
var arrayURLToSearch = [];
parseXlsx('foo.xlsx', function(err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;
    for(var i=1; i<2; i++){
        arrayURLToSearch[i] = data[i][0];
    }

console.log(arrayURLToSearch[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is asyncronous, so `console.log(arrayURLToSearch[0]);` line will be executed before `parseXlsx` method.

One solution is to use a `callback` function.

```
function execute(callback){
   var parseXlsx = require('excel');
   var arrayURLToSearch = [];
   parseXlsx('foo.xlsx', function(err, data) {
     if(err) throw err;
     for(var i=1; i<2; i++){
         arrayURLToSearch[i] = data[i][0];
     }
     callback(arrayURLToSearch);
   });
}
execute(function(arrayURLToSearch){
     console.log(arrayURLToSearch[0]);
});
```

Comment: @downvoter, please explain the reason.

Comment: Don't answer garbage questions to rep-farm.

Comment: perhaps its the 2nd part of your sentence - because `parseXlsx` is called - its the callback.

Comment: thanks for the answer, how i can resolve?

Comment: @OiRc, i will update my answer in few moments.